# Connect keyboard and synthesizer via MIDI Thru

Tags: midi, keyboard, synthesizer, audio

I have an old synthesizer with the five-pin MIDI In, Out, Thru connections. I also have a keyboard with only one USB MIDI port. How can I connect both to my audio interface (has MIDI In and Out) via MIDI Thru?

Would I have to connect the keyboard to MIDI In in the synthesizer via an adapter and then connect it to the audio interface via MIDI Thru? Or is it also possible via a MIDI Thru Box? How can I do it the other way around? So going from Synth to Keyboard to Audio Interface?

What I plan is to do a daisy chain like [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/midi-tutorial/topologies).

**EDIT:**

What I practically want to do is to play notes on my keyboard and it shall trigger the Synth playing the same notes.

Comment: Why do you need both connected to the audio interface? It is possible, with a computer, to make a bridge between the usb midi and the din midi of the interface.

Comment: @Tom And then it's possible to use keyboard and synth in chain mode as you would connect them via midi thru?

Comment: The box you call your audio interface, it provides (1) a USB audio device, and (2) a USB MIDI device, to your computer. One box, one USB cable, but the computer sees multiple devices. The USB MIDI keyboard provides another USB MIDI device to your computer. The USB MIDI keyboard cannot be directly connected, and it cannot directly talk, to the old DIN MIDI keyboard. The USB MIDI keyboard can only talk with your computer. Now the important thing you do not tell in your question is: what do you want to DO with all these devices?

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica I updated my question. By playing the keyboard I would like to trigger the Synthesizer playing. Can I then record audio data from the Synth while playing the keys from the keyboard?

Comment: You'll have to use a software application in your computer that can route MIDI messages from the USB MIDI keyboard, via the USB MIDI interface inside the box you call "audio interface", into the old synth. Something like Cubase, Ableton Live, Studio One, Reaper, GarageBand, Logic, ProTools, Bitwig, Harrison Mixbus, Sibelius, Finale, Renoise, Cakewalk, Digital Performer, Reason,  FL Studio, MPC Beats. To name a few. Or instead of the computer, you could use a standalone DAW-in-a-box such as Akai Force or MPC.

Comment: I am using Ableton. Thx, I will find out how to do that

Comment: Your question is unclear. What you should ask (to us, and yourself) is what you want to do and the purpose of it. Do you want to get all MIDI events of your keyboard *while* playing the synth? Do you want to play the synth from the keyboard while also getting events *played* by the synth? Is that synth able to send out events not originated by it? [lots of other question that may result depending on your purpose and the capabilities of both the synth and the keyboard]. If you're not sure about how the process works, don't ask about the process you *think* you want, but your actual purpose.

Comment: OK, sry now I edited the question once again and wrote an answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I achieved my goal without using MIDI Thru. Both, synth and keyboard, are connected via USB directly to the PC. In Ableton Live I routed the MIDI from the Keyboard to the Synth. And then I recorded the addio coming out of the Synth. That's exactly what I wanted. Sorry if I wasn't that precise.

Comment: Ok, for future reference, always consider to put yourself in other's shoes when asking questions: we don't know your specific problem, and, unless your question is detailed enough, it will be difficult to anybody to answer you; we may provide vague solutions that may not be applicable to your case, or even *wrong* solutions that will make you (and them) loose a lot of time trying to fix a wrong problem because the explanation was unclear or unspecific. Remember that only you really know about your problem: always imagine yourself as being asked about something you know nothing about.